# Compiling .tex file and generating pdf using a bash script in Windows

Tags: texlive, windows, scripts, bash

I am trying to compile & generate pdf from a .tex file using a bash script to automate the process. I need to use bash script as there are a large number of .tex files to be handled.

I am using this command line in my bash script:

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape ./$name.tex >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If I follow this procedure I get an error stating

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Here is the link of the log file: https://gigamove.rz.rwth-aachen.de/d/id/eFnjEFcPboHcTK

However, if I manually compile the same .tex file. it gets compiled without any such error. Also, if I simply compile it from commanline without using bash script, then also, it works surprisingly fine.
And \begin{document} is there. I already checked.

I am wondering if there is some other command line for pdflatex which could be run successfully using a bash script.

OS: Windows 10
running bash scripts using ubuntu terminal or shell command line
texlive

TIA

Comment: You may want to take off the `>/dev/null 2>&1` on your line and see exactly what errors you're getting and verify that you're running with the value of `$name` that you think you are. On my Mac, creating a single-line shell script with your text had pdflatex run on the file `.tex` which has apparently been sitting in my directory since 8 Oct 2004. Changing `$name` to `test` had the file run as expected.

Comment: `./$name.tex` ? This should not be some  argument (`$1`, `$2, ... `) of the bash script?

Comment: $name is not directly argument of the bash script but it is a variant created using the argument. For instance, argument is x.tex and then $name would be x_1.tex, x_2.tex which gets updated in the bash script.

Comment: I am getting the same error again if I use directly the name of the file as well instead of $name.tex. Let me know if I could provide you with some other info to help you understand better. Here is the link of the log file with errors: https://gigamove.rz.rwth-aachen.de/d/id/eFnjEFcPboHcTK